# MongoDb Slows down, When mongoDb write operations are more than 10000/sec

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions

I am running a cron whose code is written in golang, and i am using mongoDb as database
There was 128GB Ram into my system in which DataBase is stored, and I am using different system for the code.
The cron is running with 17000 merchants parallely, each merchant having different database, which means there was 17000 Db's into system.

Now I will tell you the scenario,
When the cron Runs, there are approximately 10000 write/insert operations per seconds, which makes mongodb slow and it affects the performance of the mongodb as well as the overall cron. The write operations include Bulk Insert queries as well as single Insertion and moreover these queries are being executed concurrently for different merchants.

To overcome this problem, I'm thinking to use [Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/transactions/) for write operations, will it make an positive impact on the slow down of mongodb. Is there anything else which i can implement to improve the performance of mongoDb, that doesn't slows it down.

Answer (score 2):

The transactions will not make your performance faster. The transactions will add additional locks in the database which might degrade the performance further.

If you are inserting 10k writes per second the MongoDB performance will be impacted. The writes are required to be processed and replicated across the replicas. During this massive writes, you will notice degraded performance.

There are several strategies to overcome this problem

- **Shard the database:** You can shard the mongo DB so that the writes are scattered into multiple nodes.
- **Space the writes:** Instead of writing at 10k/sec you can write slowly with some delay. This will smooth out the write spike and you will see the not-very-degraded performance. Maybe You can write 100 merchants' data in parallel at a time instead of 17k merchants.
- **Bigger machine:** You could try to use bigger machines to accommodate the high write throughput or play with MongoDB performance tuning parameters. This is not an ideal solution but sometime when nothing works this is the last resort.

**Good resources**

- https://www.mongodb.com/basics/best-practices
- https://stackify.com/mongodb-performance-tuning/
- https://medium.com/idealo-tech-blog/advanced-mongodb-performance-tuning-2ddcd01a27d2
- https://medium.com/mongodb-performance-tuning